# Capture and change system's date

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I am working on a "small" **windows form application** project, which starts an other **old application**. The old application needs the date to be **1/6/2015** to open. So I am trying to "capture" the **current date** into **variables**, to change the system date so the old application to start and when the old application finish, I want to brink back the current system date.

So I am trying something like this...

```
Dim _CurrentYear As Integer = Now.Date.Year
Dim _CurrentMonth As Integer = Now.Date.Month
Dim _CurrentDay As Integer = Now.Date.Day

Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateString = CType(New Date(2015, 6, 1), String)

Dim MyProcess As Process = Process.Start(OldApplication)
MyProcess.WaitForExit()

Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateString = CType(New Date(_CurrentYear, _CurrentMonth, _CurrentDay), String)
```

And I get this exception...

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "29/11/2018" to type 'Date' is not valid.'
```

Any I idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Would it not make more sense to run the old program in a VM dedicated just to it and leave it with a past date all the time, rather than trying to use a *global setting* to solve a *local problem*?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I have to make it run through this new application!!!

Comment: This really makes no sense. Windows requires elevated (admin) privileges in order to change the system time. This means that in order for your workaround to work, you have to run your app under elevated privileges in order to defeat the expiration date of software (most likely a trial or time-limited license restriction). Wouldn't it be easier and safer to either run the old app in a VM that is permanently in the past or (better yet) buy an actual license that isn't expired for the software?

Comment: @KenWhite: I have to make it run through this new application. And I can't buy a new license or something because this application stopped being developed since 2016!!!

Answer (score 0):

To capture the current date use

```
 Dim dt As DateTime = Now
```

Then change

```
 Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateString = dt.ToString
```

Comment: Are you running the program as an administrator?